# NodeJS polyfill runtime

Tags: node.js, internationalization, polyfills, kraken.js

In my krakenjs / nodejs application I'm using dust and dust-intl to format dates.

As you can read [here](http://formatjs.io/guides/runtime-environments/#polyfill-node) to add support to other languages I have to polyfill the runtime. In the same page they provide a function, but how do I have to include this code in my project?

This is the code they say I should use:

```
var areIntlLocalesSupported = require('intl-locales-supported');

var localesMyAppSupports = [
    /* list locales here */
];

if (global.Intl) {
    // Determine if the built-in `Intl` has the locale data we need.
    if (!areIntlLocalesSupported(localesMyAppSupports)) {
        // `Intl` exists, but it doesn't have the data we need, so load the
        // polyfill and replace the constructors with need with the polyfill's.
        require('intl');
        Intl.NumberFormat   = IntlPolyfill.NumberFormat;
        Intl.DateTimeFormat = IntlPolyfill.DateTimeFormat;
    }
} else {
    // No `Intl`, so use and load the polyfill.
    global.Intl = require('intl');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The polyfill defines `global.Intl`, so a standard include will do the trick. Probably right at the top of your app.

`var intlPolyfill = require('../path/to/polyfill/file.js')`

Or you could plunk that polyfill code into your main app file. Again, it alters `global`, so the change takes affect across all of your code. Just don't include/run the polyfill code after any code that needs to use the polyfilled `Intl`.

Finally, in cases where the polyfill has to define `global.Intl`, it uses a node package ('intl') to define it, so you'll need to make sure you have that package installed.